# AS3 Moving vertical and on a random point

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have code here that should have a linked movie clip be generated randomly on top of the stage. It does generate randomly but not on top. Also the items generated are supposed to move down and disappear, but it doesn't.

I am currently making a game designed for Android smartphones..

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
//Create an enemies array
var enemies:Array;
enemies = new Array();


makeEnemies();
moveEnemies();




//Call this function for how many enemies you want to make...
function makeEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
    //Make sure a Library item linkage is set to Enemy...
    tempEnemy = new Enemy();
    tempEnemy.speed = 20;
    tempEnemy.x = Math.random()* 800;
    tempEnemy.cacheAsBitmapMatrix = tempEnemy.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
    tempEnemy.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    trace("enemy");
    addChild(tempEnemy);
    enemies.push(tempEnemy);


    tempEnemy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, killEnemies);
}




function killEnemies(event:MouseEvent):void {
trace("tap");
}

//Create an enemies array if you do not already have one...
//Create tempEnemy from Enemy library item if you do not already have one...
function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];

        //rotate the enemy between 10-5 degrees
        tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*50-5));
        //Find the rotation and move the x position that direction
        tempEnemy.x -=  (Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
        if (tempEnemy.x < 0)
        {
            tempEnemy.x = 0;
        }
        if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth)
        {
            tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth;
        }

        if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
        {

            //Remove enemy from enemies array
            removeEnemy(i);
            //Subtract a life
            trace("awwwww");
        }
    }
}

function removeEnemy(idx:int)
{
    removeChild(enemies[idx]);
    enemies.splice(idx,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call the moveEnemies(); every frame, like so:

```
import flash.event.Event;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter_frame);
function onEnter_frame(e:Event):void {
    moveEnemies();
}
```

also, it might be a good idea to set the type of your enemy to Enemy instead of MovieClip

```
var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();
```